Stacking two images centrally using Bootstrap 5
I have a bootstrap row of two columns, and in one column need to have a semi opaque background image covering the entire thing with a dark background below it, to create contrast for a logo to be centered within the div.
So I have tried all sorts of ways to do this, but cannot find a way out in a reponsive way.
In the pen below I need the coffee photo covering the entire div as if it was a background image; object fit just isn't working for me, and I don't want any overflow beyond the div.
And the logo should be centered within the div overlaying that photo. Using bootstrap 5.


.wrapper {
  background: black;
}
.overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}
.logo {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 translate: -50%, -50%;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
      <h3>Title here</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu tortor eget sem elementum malesuada. Sed ac arcu nec magna facilisis aliquet. Sed ac pellentesque tortor. Quisque consequat dolor non iaculis molestie.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 wrapper">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302899/pexels-photo-302899.jpeg" width="800px" height="575px" class="overlay object-fit-cover">
      <img src="https://www.bluecapcoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Lavazza.png" class="logo" width="150px" height:"150px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Basically you want logo to be centered vertically and horizontal for all screen size. Right ?

Interesting. I have just ordered 10 packs of Lavazza 30 minutes ago

Play with this - https://codepen.io/qeeebmnq-the-looper/pen/dyBZqEM. Your wrapper div needs a height since the wrapper is the containing element of the image. Canvas sets the bk image to the full background div.

@ZADorkMan you have a few errors in your code the reason why it is not working. Also, you're technically incorrect. You don't and should not use ' canvas'.  Simply use background-size: cover if you want to go this route. You also need to remove the comma from the translate values to work correctly. The wrapper does not need a height as its height is set through the Bootstrap grid (flexbox).

Thank you - yes I think I copied wrong https://codepen.io/qeeebmnq-the-looper/pen/dyBZqEM,  but your answer is better I think. I meant 'cover' and not canvas, apologies, still early.

Just follow the Bootstrap Documentation: position:
The container needs the class: position-relative
The logo element needs the classes: position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle
the overlay should also get the class w-100 to not overflow and allow object-fit-cover to work.


.overlay {
  opacity: .5;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex justify-content-center flex-column">
      <h3>Title here</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc eu tortor eget sem elementum malesuada. Sed ac arcu nec magna facilisis aliquet. Sed ac pellentesque tortor. Quisque consequat dolor non iaculis molestie.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 wrapper position-relative">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/302899/pexels-photo-302899.jpeg" class="overlay object-fit-cover w-100">
      <img src="https://www.bluecapcoffee.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Lavazza.png" class="logo position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" width="150px" height:"150px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Perfect thank's so much. I was missed appying the w-100; I had read that the image needed width value declared which I had done but was unaware it needed 100% width in the css. Thanks again
